# How to use value converter in combination with rio binding in mmvmcross?

Tags: xamarin.forms, binding, mvvmcross

I am using rio binding. Now I want to use the MVXConverter, but I do not know how to bind a property with a ValueConverter... The mvx.bi.nd let me bind a property, but never saw an example with using a converter. Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: Could you provide some code showing what you've already tried? Also, see the documentation provided here: https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/fundamentals/value-converters

Comment: Are you doing it using Xamarin.Forms?